# Rails password can't be blank error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a user signup form in Rails 4.1.6.  I keep getting a 'password can't be blank' error.  I can see that both the password and password_confirmation are in the params hash but not in the params[:user] sub-hash.  I cannot figure out why for the life of me.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :company

    has_secure_password

end
```

Users Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    respond_to :json

    def index
        @users = User.all
        respond_with(@users)
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        @user.save
        respond_with(@user)
    end


    private

        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:given_name, :family_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
        end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your parameters are not being sent to the server correctly.

`password` should be sent as `user[password]` and `password_confirmation` should be sent as `user[password_confirmation]`.

See documentation for [hash and array parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters).

Alternatively, adding `wrap_parameters` to the controller will wrap parameters into a nested hash.

`wrap_parameters :user, include: [:given_name, :family_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation]`

See documentation for [ActionController::ParamsWrapper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html).

Comment: The documentation helped.  I had to add the following to my users controller: wrap_parameters :user, include: [:given_name, :family_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation].  It works!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Neat, I wasn't aware of `wrap_parameters`.  I updated my answer to include that.